# Connecting firebird to adf using ODBC connection string

Tags: azure, firebird

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzYwx.png)

This is the connection String i am using -
DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;UID=[SYSDBA];PWD=[firebird];DBNAME=[192.168.1.7/3050]:[D:\demodb.FDB]

Comment: Please ask an actual question and provide the error message as text, and not as a screenshot. In any case, the problem seems to be your use of square brackets around values. Remove them. Also, what are you trying to do, where is the system located trying to connect, and where is the Firebird server located, because 192.168.1.7 is a network-local IP address and is not routable over the internet, so unless both systems are on the same network, that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection string square brackets are not needed.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/